# php array limit not exceeding more than 970

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, data-structures

I am working in laravel system. when I do create or update from blade I am getting an array of results like this to save or update in the database.

```
$kitchenList = $request->input('kitchens', [])??[];
```

But I am facing an issue with array length when array length increases more than 970. It is giving only 970 elements. The rest of the elements are missing.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Is this a GET request? GET requests are limited to 2K-ish bytes depending on browser, you're likely bumping up against that. Just change to POST if so and you should be good.

Comment: it is a put request.

Comment: try to raise post_max_size in your php.ini

Comment: you can set the value more than now for parameter **memory_limit** in your **php.ini** file.